# Does `Property` path syntax supports casting in Avalonia, like in WPF?

Tags: c#, xaml, avaloniaui, propertypath

Often in WPF we need to cast property to specific type to be able to access further properties in the path, e.g. from [some answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50799095/1997232):

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
```

Here we cast `Ellipse.RenderTransform` to `TranslateTransform` first, so that we can specify `X` as a target property.

How can I do the same in Avalonia to target e.g. control's `Effect` property?

---

Here is what I want:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Effect>
        <BlurEffect Radius="0"/> <!-- I want to access Radius -->
    </Grid.Effect>
    <Grid.Transitions>
        <Transitions>
            <DoubleTransition Property="(Grid.Effect).(BlurEffect.Radius)"
                              Duration="1"/> <!-- AVLN:0004 - Internal compiler error while transforming node XamlX.Ast.XamlAstXamlPropertyValueNode: Avalonia.Data.Core.ExpressionParseException: Expected end of expression. -->
        </Transitions>
    </Grid.Transitions>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Why not without the casting? because `to be able to access further properties in the path` seems only valid for the xaml designer and the path will be evaluated at runtime just fine without the casting.

Comment: so instead of `Property="(Grid.Effect).(BlurEffect.Radius)"` I would assume this to work `Property="Effect.Radius"`

Comment: @RandRandom, `Property="Effect.Radius"` will throw *AVLN:0004 - Unable to find RadiusProperty field on type Avalonia.Media.Effect,Avalonia.Base*

Comment: Did you activate compiled bindings? https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/data-binding/compiled-bindings

Comment: What have bindings to do with property path? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

It does support this, [but the syntax is slightly different from WPF](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/basics/data/data-binding/compiled-bindings#type-casting).

```xml
<Button Command="{Binding $parent[ItemsRepeater].((vm:MyUserControlViewModel)DataContext).DoItCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding ItemId}"/>
```